# Spring Batch Runtime Exception in Item processor

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am learning spring batch and trying to understand how item processor works, during exception.

I am reading data from csv file in a chunk of 3 records and process it and write it to Database.

my csv file

```
Jill,Doe
Joe,Doe
Justin,Doe
Jane,Doe
John,Doem
Jill,Doe
Joe,Doe
Justin,Doe
Jane,Doe
```

Batch Configuration, reading items in chunk of 3 , and skip limit 2

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>().name("personItemReader").resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv")).delimited()
                .names(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" }).fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(Person.class);
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>().itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql("INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)").dataSource(dataSource).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener).flow(step1).end().build();
    }

   @Bean
public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Person, Person> chunk(3).reader(reader()).processor(processor()).writer(writer).faultTolerant().skipLimit(2)
            .skip(Exception.class).build();
}
   }
```

I am trying to simulate a Exception, by throwing Exception manually for one record in my item processor

```
public class PersonItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Person, Person> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonItemProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public Person process(final Person person) throws Exception {
        final String firstName = person.getFirstName().toUpperCase();
        final String lastName = person.getLastName().toUpperCase();

        final Person transformedPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName);

        log.info("Converting (" + person + ") into (" + transformedPerson + ")");
        if (person.getLastName().equals("Doem"))
            throw new Exception("DOOM");
        return transformedPerson;
    }
}
```

Now as per skip limit, when the exception is thrown, the item processor is re processing the chunk and skips the item which throws error and item write also  inserts all records in DB , except the one record with exception.

This is all fine, because my processor, it is just converting lower to upper case name, and it can be run many times with out impact.

But lets assume if my item processor, is calling web service and sending data.
and if some exception is thrown after successful calling for web service. then remaining data in the chunk will be processed again (and calling webservice again). 
I don't want to call web service again, because it is like sending duplicate data to web service and the webservice system cannot identify duplicate data.

How to handle such case. one option is don't skip Exception, which means my still one record in the chunk will not make it to item writer, even though the  processor had called web service. so that is not correct.

other option chunk should be of size 1 , then this may not be efficient in processing thousands of records.

what are the other options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, your item processor is not idempotent. However, the [Fault tolerance](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#faultTolerant) section of the documentation says that the item processor should be idempotent when using a fault tolerant step. Here is an excerpt:

> If a step is configured to be fault tolerant (typically by using skip or retry processing), any ItemProcessor used should be implemented in a way that is idempotent.

Comment: If item Processor should be idempotent. then I assume that any exception (like web service down, or any data issue) to be handled manually within item processor,   (like sending error detail to item writer to update DB ) instead of throwing it. since all exception handled within item processor,  so roll back will  not happen and item reader can retry those error records in next execution.

Comment: Not necessarily handled manually within item processor, for transient error (like your example of a web service temporarily down), you can configure a retry policy instead of a skip policy and it will be retried automatically according to the policy.